# Issues with ArcGIS Web AppBuilder creating custom widget by inheriting existing widget

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder, dojo

I am trying to extend the inbuilt Select widget in the ArcGIS Web AppBuilder for Desktop using dojo. According to the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/sample-code/create-custom-in-panel-widget.htm) by ESRI we always inherit the 'dijit/_WidgetBase' module to create the custom widget.

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare', 'jimu/BaseWidget'],
function(declare, BaseWidget) {
  //To create a widget, you need to derive from BaseWidget.
  return declare([BaseWidget], {
    // Custom widget code goes here 
    baseClass: 'jimu-widget-mywidget'
  });
});
```

Since I wanted the inherit he select widget I changed the code to the following:

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare', 'widgets/Select/Widget'],
function(declare, Select) {
  //To create a widget, you need to derive from BaseWidget.
  return declare([Select], {
    baseClass: 'jimu-widget-selectlsa',
    startup: function() {
      this.inherited(arguments);
      console.log("tesiting")
    }  
  });
});
```

After copying all the HTML and CSS content from the default Select widget's to my custom widget's HTML and CSS the custom Select widget works fine.

Since I have inherited the default widget's Widget.js file I am able to call functions of the default widget form my custom widget.

However, in the default widget, there is one more file named SelectableLayerItem.js which has a method name _showActions. I tired adding the following code to access the _showActions method in the SelectableLayerItem.js file:

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare', 'widgets/Select/Widget','widgets/Select/SelectableLayerItem'],
function(declare, Select, SelectableLayerItem) {
  //To create a widget, you need to derive from BaseWidget.
  return declare([Select, SelectableLayerItem], {
    baseClass: 'jimu-widget-selectlsa',
    startup: function() {
      this.inherited(arguments);
      console.log("tesiting")
    },  
    _showActions: function(){
        //overwrite
    }
  });
});
```

After running the application, the application runs without any error in the console. However, my custom widget is not able to overwrite the _showActions method in the SelectableLayerItem.js file.

Instead of calling the overwritten method it always calls the default SelectableLayerItem.js's _showActions method.

How can I inherit multiple modules and access their methods independently?